# rosbag play from time1 end time2

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, guys:
i just wander is there a command in rosbag play, could let us play a bag from time1 to time2?
BTW, i did not find such command in wiki: http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline#play

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264184/rosbag-play-from-time1-end-time2/) by [DinnerHowe](https://answers.ros.org/users/26306/dinnerhowe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 188 on 2017-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the `--start` and `--duration` options to start playback at a specific offset into a bag file, and to play for a specific period of time. This isn't quite the same as specifying absolute start and end timestamps, but with a bit of math you can use it to do the same thing.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0